# Android handler and thread mechanism

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am working with threads and handlers on android and I am a beginner on this.

Actually, there is something that is not clear yet for me: does the handler method

`void handleMessage(Message msg)`"

always runs in the UI thread?

In fact, in the offical documentation they said that "

> Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that
>   thread's message queue

and that's a little bit confusing for me because according to what I understood that means that the handler's handleMessage method runs in the thread that created it.

Help please and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A Handler runs on whatever thread it was on when it was created via new.  This thread must have a Looper object, which the UI thread has by default, and any other thread must make on their own.  So while you can have a Handler post to any thread, 99% of the time it will be on the UI thread.  It's probably safe to assume it goes to the UI thread when reading code until proved differently.

Comment: in addition to Gabe responce,  if you want a Handler in background  thread the easiest is to use hnmn... a HandlerThread class

Comment: If for some reason you want to be sure a Handler is associated with the main thread, you always have handler.getLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()

Comment: so that means that the handlers runs in the thread UI unless I create a Looper in the thread that creates  it?

Comment: Close.  It runs in whatever thread it was created in, unless you specify otherwise.  If you create it in a thread with no Looper, it will throw an exception.

Comment: so for non ui handler create a HandlerThread ht instance,  start() it,  and create a Handler with Looper param set to ht.getLooper()